# OO php direct access class method?

Tags: php, typo3

I thought I can call a method directly with `classname::method` but it didn't work. How is this possible? I traced the function call with xdebug but it gives me an error. Would it be a problem when the method needs some class variable?

This works:

```
    $a = new export_csv();
    $a->dl_csv();
```

This don't: `export_csv::dl_csv();`

I've added public static to my method to no avail. I don't get anything in the log files and xdebug stop working without an error message? Is this normal? My class includes some class and connect to my database and pull and echo some rows?

```
 require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_db.php');
 require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_div.php');
 require_once(PATH_t3lib.'utility/class.t3lib_utility_math.php');

 class export_csv 
 {
     var $filename = 'meinname.csv';

     public static function dl_csv()
     {
        // bitte nicht ändern muß zur laufzeit geladen werden
        include(PATH_typo3conf.'localconf.php');

        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_DB');
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->connectDB($typo_db_host, $typo_db_username,   
            $typo_db_password, $typo_db);

        session_start();
            $targetCat = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['targetCat']);

            // calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the 
            result
            $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(  'V.title VT, V.uid VU,  
            S.title ST, S.uid SU, S1.uid S1U, S1.title S1T',
                                                    'tx_category V
                                                    INNER JOIN tx_category S ON  

                                                    V.parent_category=S.uid
                                                    INNER JOIN tx_category S1 ON 
                                                    S.parent_category=S1.uid',
                                                    'V.uid='.$targetCat.' OR S.uid='.
                                                     $targetCat.' OR S1.uid='.
                                                     $targetCat.
                                                    ' AND V.deleted=0 AND V.hidden=0',
                                                    '',
                                                    '',
                                                    ''
                            );                      
    $arrcount=0;
    while ( $row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res) )
    {
        $categories[] = mysql_real_escape_string($row["VU"]);
        ++$arrcount;
    }

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type:text/comma-separated-values");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$this->filename");

    if ( $arrcount )
    {
        $res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*',
                                                      'tx_download',
                                                      'category IN('.implode(",",
                                                      $categories).")",
                                                      '',
                                                      "",
     ""                                                  
                                                    );
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
        {
            $s = array ();
            $s[] = $row['1'];
            $s[] = $row['2'];
            $s[] = $row['3'];
            $s[] = $row['4'];
            $s[] = $row['5'];

            echo '"'. substr ( implode ( '","', $s ),0,strlen ( implode ( '","', $s) ) - 2  ) . "\r\n";

        }       
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: code example? and: it's ``classname::method`` not the other way round ;-). Is method ``static`` and ``public``?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your problem getting there?

Comment: After you posted your code, we need to know the contents of `dl_csv()`. If it isn't a static method, you should not be calling it statically.

Comment: @Michael: Maybe it's Typo3 specific question? I've addem my method dl_csv() and the full class.

Comment: @Chiyou See my changes below - you _do_ have a `$this` inside there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods defined as `static`, which therefore cannot make use of instance properties/methods (via `$this`) can be called statically via:

```
ClassName::methodname();

// Static method definition:
public static function methodname() {
  echo "I'm the method, I don't use \$this in any way!";
  // Any attempt to use $this in here would result in error.
}
```

Review the PHP documentation on [`static` methods and properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

#### Update after seeing mode code:

Your `dl_csv()` function accesses `$this->filename` in the output headers, which is invalid inside a static call.

```
// Can't do this!
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$this->filename");
```

Instead, you would need to define the `$filename` as a static property as well and call via `self::`:

```
// Top of the class:
// Instead of the old PHP4 var keyword, define $filename as a public static property
public static $filename = 'meinname.csv';

// Later...
// Inside your method header() call:
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . self::$filename);
```

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed my code but there are a lot of $this-> in the other method calls from Typo3 hence it doesn't work? Xdebug just stops and doesn't give anything back and I don't have anything in my php error log file?

Comment: @Chiyou If there are multiple other `$this`, then it is likely not going to be practical for you to make a static call to that function. If it wasn't intended & engineered to be used that way, it probably shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

It is `Class::method();`, however I'm really curious as to why you think you need it to be accessible throughout your entire application (`global`ly).

You may be interested in [dependency injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/) instead.

Comment: First off, curiosity and second: I don't have to type so much?

Comment: First: fine with me. Second isn't a valid reason :-). It is your job to be lazy as a programmer, but not when it prevents you from testing your code and giving you more work later. You are making it impossible (hard) to unit test your code when you are using `static` methods.